# how to get the month number from multiple years in datetime dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following datetime dataframe :

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2015 ,2016,2014], 'month': [2,11, 3,9], 'day': [4,21, 5,10]})

   df = pd.to_datetime(df)
```

I want to get the 'month_number'. My desired result corresponding to the sequential month count across the multiple years would be:

6
15
19
1

Comment: how can month number be 15?

Comment: @FlashThunder not month number, count of months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(df.year - min(df.year))*12 + df.month

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
In [5078]: df.month + 12*(df.year - df.year.iloc[0])
Out[5078]:
0     2
1    11
2    15
dtype: int64
```

Same as

```
In [5079]: df.month.add(df.year.sub(df.year.iloc[0]).mul(12))
Out[5079]:
0     2
1    11
2    15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: if I have this dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2015 ,2016,2014],
                       'month': [2,11, 3,9],
                       'day': [4,21, 5,10]})  
df = pd.to_datetime(df)` , how can I get this output: 6,15,19,1